# How to calculate the Silhouette Score for each cluster separately in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

You can easily extract the silhouette score with 1 line of code that averages the scores for all your clusters but how do you extract each of the intermediate scores from the scikit learn implementation of the silhouette score? I want to be able to extract this same score for each cluster individually, not only get the total score.

```
metrics.silhouette_score(x, y, metric='euclidean')
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your data looks something like this:

```
num_clusters = 3
X, y = datasets.load_iris(return_X_y=True)
kmeans_model = KMeans(n_clusters=num_clusters, random_state=1).fit(X)
cluster_labels = kmeans_model.labels_
```

You could use [`metrics.silhouette_samples`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.silhouette_samples.html) to compute the silhouette coefficients for each sample, then take the mean of each cluster:

```
sample_silhouette_values = metrics.silhouette_samples(X, cluster_labels)

means_lst = []
for label in range(num_clusters):
    means_lst.append(sample_silhouette_values[cluster_labels == label].mean())
```

---

```
print(means_lst)                                                                             
[0.4173199215409322, 0.7981404884286224, 0.45110506043401194] # 1 mean for each of the 3 clusters
```

Comment: When I try to run the code you have provided, I get IndexError: too many indices for array, not sure why? The X and cluster_labels are just the dataframe with all the independent variables for X and dependent variable for cluster_labels right?

Comment: Make sure the _X_ and _clusterlabels_ variables are numpy arrays, instead of dataframes. Did you receive the IndexError when running the code using the sample iris dataset?