# How to calculate the Silhouette Score for the whole cluster

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, silhouette

we can easily extract the silhouette score for each sample. If our data looks something like this: I want to be able to calculate the silhouette score for the whole cluster solution

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


X = np.array([0.85142858,0.85566274,0.85364912,0.81536489,0.84929932,0.85042336,0.84899714,
         0.82019115, 0.86112067,0.8312496 ])
X=X.reshape(-1, 1)

num_clusters = 3
kmeans_model = KMedoids(n_clusters=num_clusters, random_state=1).fit(X)
cluster_labels = kmeans_model.labels_
```

Comment: Have you seen the documentation of sklearn about this? I think it answers your question perfectly: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_kmeans_silhouette_analysis.html.

Comment: @ sandertjuh thank you, what about calculating SI for the whole cluster?

Comment: simply take the mean silhouette score of each sample in each cluster. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59919627/how-to-calculate-the-silhouette-score-for-each-cluster-separately-in-python

Comment: @ sandertjuh the Silhouette Score for each cluster separately is calculated, not for the whole cluster solution?

Comment: the Silhouette Score can be calculated for each sample in your data set, each cluster in your data set, and the entire data set. The last two are both averages of the first one. If you want one silhouette score for the entire (clustered) data set, simply call `silhouette_score`. See docs: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.silhouette_score.html